# Google Chrome stays locked after loging in with fingerprint?

Tags: login, password, authentication, fingerprint-reader

Whenever I log in with my fingerprint sensor Google chrome stays locked and needs a password to gain access to my Google account.
And is there anyway to authenticate with fingerprint?